# Possible to do local cloud builds?

Tags: nativescript

I want to develop a NativeScript application on my Linux machine and do a local build for iOS using my Mac Mini. Is this "local cloud" setup possible?

Comment: I don't think so, as of now it's not possible to setup your own remote machine for cloud builds. You might want to submit a feature request.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't find any way to do it either and I appreciate the confirmation. If you put your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by Manoj in the comments, at the time of this writing (April 2019) there is not a real solution for implementing the "local cloud" as described. I submitted a feature request to the Nativescript team that you can find here (https://github.com/NativeScript/sidekick-feedback/issues/365).

In the comments of that issue on github Nathanael A. recommended the following workaround:

> @NathanaelA commented on Mon Apr 08 2019
>
> Not sure if this will work for you; but my current way I work is I do everything in phpStorm on Linux (used to use Windows, so it works from windows also). phpStorm I have set to automatically sync to the same folder on the mac (via ssh). On the mac I just do tns run when I first start; and then ignore the mac for the rest of the time. phpStorm will keep everything in sync with the mac, and the mac will keep everything in sync with the phone/simulator on it.
>
> I don't know if vscode has a automatic sync on file change plugin; but you can probably whip something up with node and file watching to do the same thing...

**UPDATE:** `lsyncd` wasn't actually working and in the end I was not able to make it work. Instead,  I used `inotify-hookable` and this command, which turns out to be extremely effective and much, much simpler:

```
inotify-hookable -rw /mnt/projects/my-drawer-ng/ -c 'rsync -avr /mnt/projects/my-drawer-ng jhudson@192.168.241.129:/Users/jhudson/Documents/my-drawer-ng/'
```

It will setup a watch on all the files in the directory, and then execute the command passed to `-c` whenever one of them changes.

<s>I was able to successfully implement this workaround between an Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine and my Mac OS X machine with the `lsyncd` package.</s>

Installation instructions for `lsyncd` can be found at https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_16.04&p=lsync and are reproduced below:

```sh
root@dlp:~# apt-get -y install lsyncd
root@dlp:~# mkdir /etc/lsyncd 
root@dlp:~# vi /etc/lsyncd/lsyncd.conf.lua
# create new
 settings{
    statusFile = "/tmp/lsyncd.stat",
    statusInterval = 1,
}
sync{
    default.rsync,
    # source directory
    source="/root/work/",
    # destination Hostname or IP address:(the name set in rsyncd.conf)
    target="10.0.0.31::backup",
    # excluding list
    excludeFrom="/etc/rsync_exclude.lst",
}

root@dlp:~# systemctl restart lsyncd
```

Note: You need to remove the "comments" from the lua file, and you need to create the file `/etc/rsync_exclude.lst` if it doesn't already exist. Alternatively you could remove the line `excludeFrom="..."` from the config file.